# Add and count non-zero values of rows based on current date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 account_id contract_id 2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-06-01 00:00:00
0   1   A   200.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   1   B   300.0   300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   1   C   0.0 0.0 0.0 400.0   400.0   400.0   400.0
3   2   K   100.0   100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   2   F   0.0 0.0 50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0
```

I want the following output:

```
 account_id contract_id total   active_months   2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-06-01 00:00:00
 0  1   A   200 1   200.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 1  1   B   600 2   300.0   300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 2  1   C   1200    3   0.0 0.0 0.0 400.0   400.0   400.0   400.0
 3  2   K   300 3   100.0   100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 4  2   F   200 4   0.0 0.0 50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0
```

In this example, the current date set is "May 1, 2021". I want to add and count (only non-zero) the values from the third column up to the column of the current date. The total column should show the sum while the active_months should show the count of non-zero values based on the current date set.

Here's the dictionary for the dataframe:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'contract_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'K', 4: 'F'},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 200.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0}}
```

Here's the dictionary for the output:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'contract_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'K', 4: 'F'},
 'total': {0: 200, 1: 600, 2: 1200, 3: 300, 4: 200},
 'active_months': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 200.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 50.0}}
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can filter the required columns using boolean indexing, then calculate and insert the `total` and `active_months` columns in `df` where `total` is computed by summing up the values along `axis=1` and `active_months` is calculated by counting non-zero values along `axis=1`

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce') <= '1 May, 2021'
c = df.loc[:, m]

df.insert(2, 'total', c.sum(1))
df.insert(3, 'active_months', c.ne(0).sum(1))
```

---

```
>>> df

   account_id contract_id   total  active_months  2020-12-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-02-01 00:00:00  2021-03-01 00:00:00  2021-04-01 00:00:00  2021-05-01 00:00:00  2021-06-01 00:00:00
0           1           A   200.0              1                200.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
1           1           B   600.0              2                300.0                300.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
2           1           C  1200.0              3                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                400.0                400.0                400.0                400.0
3           2           K   300.0              3                100.0                100.0                100.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0
4           2           F   200.0              4                  0.0                  0.0                 50.0                 50.0                 50.0                 50.0                 50.0
```

Comment: Can you also help me with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67348458/add-columns-based-on-condition-from-another-column

Answer (score 1):

You can try a combination of melt, and groupby:

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['account_id', 'contract_id'], var_name='date')
df_melt = df_melt[(df_melt['date']<='2021-05-01') & (df_melt['value']>0)]
df_melt = df_melt.groupby(['account_id', 'contract_id']).agg(active_months=('value', 'count'), total=('value', 'sum')).reset_index()
df = df.merge(df_melt, on=['account_id', 'contract_id'])
```

Output

[image: Output]